# 426 Status: WebSockets with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, websocket, http-status-codes

Im currently switching my application from using **Socket.io** to **HTML5 WebSockets**. I'm assuming that my problem lies within the first couple lines of both the client and server. My browser keeps on replying with a 426 (Upgrade Required) status when I test my app on localhost. Please shed some light on my problem...

*Server Code*

```
"use strict";
var session = require('./chat-session'),
        serveStatic = require('serve-static'),
        server = require('http').createServer(),
        WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server,
        wss = new WebSocketServer({server: server, port: 8181}),
        express = require('express'),
        app = express();
        // Sockets with real-time data
        // io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
        // mongoose = require('mongoose');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); // used for external files on client
let storage = session.default; // cache object for storage

// Routing refers to determining how an application responds to a client request to a particular endpoint
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

wss.on('connection', function(client){

    client.on('join', (name) => {
        client.nickname = name;
        // check to see if nickname has been taken, if so, give random name
        if(storage.users.indexOf(client.nickname) !== -1) {client.nickname = randomName();}
        // tell all chatters that a new user has entered the room
        client.broadcast.emit("enter", "* " + client.nickname + " * has connected");

        storage.users.forEach((user) => {
            client.emit('add chatter', user);
        });

        client.broadcast.emit('add chatter', client.nickname);

        storage.channels.general.messages.forEach((message) => {
            client.emit("message", message.name + ": " + message.data, 'general');
        });

        storage.users.push(client.nickname);
    });

    client.on('message', (message, room) => {
        var nickname = client.nickname;
        client.broadcast.emit("message", nickname + ": " + message, room);
        client.emit("me", message); // send message to self

        storeMessage(nickname, message, room); // store the message in chat-session

        console.log(nickname + ' said: ' + message + " in room " + room);
    });

    // When client switches between tabs (rooms)
    client.on('switch', (room) => {
        storage.channels[room].messages.forEach((message) => {
            if (message.name === client.nickname) {
                client.emit("me", message.data, room);
            } else {
                client.emit("message", message.name + ": " + message.data, room);
            }
        });
    });

//  client.on('disconnect', () => {
//      client.emit('disconnect', "client")
//  });

});

//const PORT = 8080;
//server.listen(PORT);
```

*Client Code*

```
    // var server = io.connect("http://localhost:8080"); // connect to server
var server = new WebSocketServer("ws://localhost:8181");
var curRoom = $('.nav .active').attr('id'); // cache current room

server.on('connect', function(data){
        nickname = prompt("What is your nickname?");
        //while(nickname) TODO:make sure client cannot choose null
        server.emit('join', nickname); // notify the server of the users nickname
});

//server.on('disconnect', function(data){
//  server.emit('disconnect');
//});

// new chatter enters room
server.on('enter', function(data){
        $('#messages').append($('<li style="background:#33cc33; color:white">').text(data));
});

// connected users section
server.on('add chatter', function(name){
        var chatter = $('<li style="color:white; font-size:22px">' + name + '</li>').data('name', name);
        $('#users').append(chatter);
});

// users' send message
server.on('message', function(message, room){
        // only emit message to other users if they are in same channel
        if (curRoom === room) {
            $('#messages').append($('<li style="display:table; box-shadow: 6px 3px 8px grey;">').text(message));
            play(); // invoke function to play sound to other clients
            console.log('sound played here');
        }
});

// differentiate how the client sees their message
server.on('me', function(message){
        $('#messages').append($('<li style="background:#0066ff; color:white; display:table; box-shadow: 6px 3px 8px grey;">').text(message));
});

// Client submits message
$('#chat_form').submit(function(e){
        var message = $("#chat_input").val();
        server.emit('message', message, curRoom);
        $('#chat_input').val(''); // Make input box blank for new message
        return false; // prevents refresh of page after submit
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Http 426 means that you are trying to connect unsupported web-socket version .
You can check in the client headers for supported version .

Refer to RFC for more detail

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-4.2.2